# Who betrayed the alliance in Wit'ch Star?

Tags: banned-and-the-banished

In the 5th book of The Banned & The Banished series, Wit'ch Star, in the early chapters Meric hears one of the El'vin captains (I don't remember her name, and don't have the book with me for reference) say "We are betrayed!" before crashing her ship into the sea.

As it turns out she had on board a shipment of ebon'stone eggs that contained the mind-controlling jellyfish monsters, which she was under the control of at the time.

Clearly whoever betrayed the alliance had caused this, and the captain managed to wrest control from the creature for long enough to warn Meric and crash the ship.

But does it ever mention who in the books actually betrayed them? From the statement, it would likely be someone the captain trusted, in order to get close enough to implant her with the creature (and probably her crew).

But I don't recall whether it mentioned specifically who was the initial person who betrayed them, and eventually managed to

> infect Hunt and Sy-Wen, along with many others.

Does it ever hint, or specifically say who the betrayer was? Or was it more of a general warning to watch out for allies who may be infected?